# How to change the year to 2020 using pandas and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

```
import pandas as pd


dates = pd.date_range('12/25/2019', periods=20, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':dates})
df['col']=pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
df['dow'] = df.col.dt.dayofweek
df['week'] = df.col.dt.to_period('W')
df['week_alt']=df.col.dt.year.astype(str) + '-w' + df.col.dt.week.astype(str)
```

With the output I get

```
col dow week    week_alt
0   2019-12-25  2   2019-12-23/2019-12-29   2019-w52
1   2019-12-26  3   2019-12-23/2019-12-29   2019-w52
2   2019-12-27  4   2019-12-23/2019-12-29   2019-w52
3   2019-12-28  5   2019-12-23/2019-12-29   2019-w52
4   2019-12-29  6   2019-12-23/2019-12-29   2019-w52
5   2019-12-30  0   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-w1
6   2019-12-31  1   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-w1
7   2020-01-01  2   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-w1
8   2020-01-02  3   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-w1
9   2020-01-03  4   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-w1
10  2020-01-04  5   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-w1
11  2020-01-05  6   2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-w1
```

From line 5 and 6 we can see that, the year jump back to 2020, how to solve?
I cant find the code to change it

Comment: _the year jump back to 2020_ It jumps **back** to 2020?

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, what I means is, from col 5 and 6, it is already 2020-w1 by right, but the output still shown 2019-w1, how to solved?

Comment: Still not clear as to what the expected output is - can you add a block with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way `datetime` processes the `week` attribute: 2019-12-30 is the monday of Week 1 of 2020. If you want it to show `2019-w53` instead of `2019-w1` you need to fix it manually.